# Error with PouchDB: TypeError: angular.factory is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, pouchdb

I'm trying to figure out how to use PouchDB in AngularJS. I'm trying to follow these instructions https://github.com/wspringer/angular-pouchdb

I think I'm having a problem understanding the syntax for creating factories and/or services. I get as far as the section on "Interacting with the database"

app.js

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('myappApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute',
    'pouchdb'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  })
angular.factory('someservice', function(pouchdb) {
  // Do something with pouchdb.
  var db = pouchdb.create('testdb');
  pouchdb.destroy('testdb');
  db.put({_id: 'foo', name: 'bar'});
});
```

When I add the "db.put", The message I see in the browser's console is:

```
 [15:17:45.343] TypeError: angular.factory is not a function @ http://127.0.0.1:9000/scripts/app.js:21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `angular` object does not have a factory method, so it will returned as undefined.

Try putting it on the object returned by the module method.

```
angular
  .module('myappApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute',
    'pouchdb'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  })
  // note the difference here, it is using the object returned by module() and config()
  .factory('someservice', function(pouchdb) {
    // Do something with pouchdb.
    var db = pouchdb.create('testdb');
    pouchdb.destroy('testdb');
    db.put({_id: 'foo', name: 'bar'});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, I was able to adapt this code example to test the DB is working
http://plnkr.co/edit/M2K7no75zonXKcXKF9Sc?p=preview

app.js
    'use strict';

```
angular
  .module('myappApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute',
    'pouchdb'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  })
  .factory('MyModel', function(pouchdb) {
    return new pouchdb.create('mydb');
  })
  .run(function (){
    var db = new PouchDB('mydb');

    db.info().then(function(info) {
      if (info.doc_count < 2) {
        db.post({display: 'Hello'});
        db.post({display: 'World'});
      }
    });
  });
```

main.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myappApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, MyModel) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
    MyModel.info().then(function(info) {
      $scope.numOfDocs = info.doc_count;
    });

    $scope.options = {
      db: MyModel,
      name: 'Visitor'
    };

    $scope.db = MyModel;
  });
```

main.html

```
  <p>Hello {{options.name}}! There are {{numOfDocs}} docs in your Pouch</p>

  <p>Root scope:</p>
  <ul>
    <li pouch-repeat="item in db" ng-bind="item.display"></li>
  </ul>

  <p>Child scope:</p>
  <ul>
    <li pouch-repeat="item in options.db" ng-bind="item.display"></li>
  </ul>
```